# javax.sound.sampled how does it work?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am trying to play a sound in Java.
So far it is going well, thank you, but I have a problem understanding how does this work.

I wrote a function that does the playback:

```
    private static void PlaySound(String path) {
        try {
            final File SoundFile = new File(path);
            AudioInputStream Sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(SoundFile);

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, Sound.getFormat());
            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(Sound);

            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
                public void update (LineEvent event) {
                    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                        event.getLine().close();
                        System.out.printf("Playback ended!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });
            System.out.printf("This sound is %f seconds long.", (clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000.0d));
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorHandler(e);
        }
    }
```

Now this function works almost fine: when the sound has ended, it calls the event.getLine().close(); function, but it is stuck in an "infinite loop" (not sure if it is) and nothing after that statement gets executed, and the program runs until I kill it manually.

If I change the line

```
if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
```

to

```
if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.CLOSE) {
```

then the sound plays, and the program exits correctly, but still none of the statement after the event.getLine().close(); are executed.

The question is: is this the intended behavior of event.getLine().close(), or I am doing something wrong?

---

Solution:

The LineListener is actually based on an outdated fact, that Java Sound has a bug in it, and we need to exit explicitly from the vm. Without the listener, the code just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

See if it's raising an exception:

```
public void update (LineEvent event) {
  if (event.getType().equals(LineEvent.Type.STOP)) {
    try { 
      event.getLine().close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.printf("Playback ended!");
  }
}
```

Comment: No exception raised from the event.getLine().close(). By the way, if there was an unhandled exception the code would actually exit with error (-:

Comment: @estol An unhandled exception would only cause the program to terminate with an error if it is in the main thread. I wanted to see if there was a `ThreadDeath` being raised because `close()` is killing an event-delivery thread.

Comment: the program at this point consist of a single thread: the function above, and a main function calling the PlaySound() function with the /home/estol/sounds/testfiles/2sec.wav parameter passed. This is just an experiment to see how this works.

Comment: @estol Using the sound packages will create additional background threads. That's why the program sometimes doesn't terminate when your main does. One of the reasons to call `close()` is to stop these threads.

Comment: sure it creates some threads, I am not entirely sure about the working mechanism of this object, but if I call close, why does it hang instead of terminate?

Comment: Also, it never terminates. Not actually a sometimes it works, sometimes it does not case... (-:

Comment: Did you actually test with a catch for `Throwable`, or did you just assume it won't have any results? Closing from a STOP event works fine for me, but platform differences are important with the sound API.

Comment: I tested it. That's why I said no exception raised from event.getLine().close() in my very first comment. (also, if I just evaluate it in my head, what would be the point to ask for help? (-:)